# Drop multiples columns from the dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I want to drop multiple columns(around 800) from the dataframe using python. I have written below code:

```
  def corr_df(x, corr_val):


    # Creates Correlation Matrix and Instantiates
    corr_matrix = x.corr()
    iters = range(len(corr_matrix.columns) - 1)
    drop_cols = []
    df_drop=pd.DataFrame()
    cols=[]
    # Iterates through Correlation Matrix Table to find correlated columns
    for i in iters:
        for j in range(i):
            item = corr_matrix.iloc[j:(j+1), (i+1):(i+2)]
            col = item.columns
            row = item.index
            val = item.values
            if val >= corr_val:
                # Prints the correlated feature set and the corr val
                #print(col.values[0], "|", row.values[0], "|", round(val[0][0], 2))
                drop_cols.append(i)

    drops = sorted(set(drop_cols))[::-1]
    df_dropped=x.drop(drops,axis=1)
    # Drops the correlated columns
#     for i in drops:
#         col=(x.iloc[:, (i+1):(i+2)].columns.values.tolist())
#         print (col)
#         df_dropped=df.drop(col, axis=1)

        #cols.append()

    #print(df_dropped)
    return (df_dropped)
```

But this code is printing the dataframe have only one column dropped. Any comments or suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `df = df.drop(lst, axis=1)`, where `lst` is your list of columns. Is there a reason why you need to perform this one at a time iteratively?

Comment: I can drop all of them once, but when I am doing the `df.drop(drops,axis=1)`. Getting `ValueError: labels [1069 1068 1067 ...,    3    2    1] not contained in axis`.

Comment: that means the columns don't exist for you to drop them.

Comment: Yup, But columns are there. I don't why it is throwing valueError.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis, I have added full code, please have a look.

Comment: are you looking to drop columns by position, or by name ?

Answer (score 1):

Drop multiple columns by numerical index like this:

```
cols = [1069, 1068, 1067]

df = df.drop(df.columns[cols], axis=1)
```